# How to implement this data structure in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am moving from C#/Java to C++ and have trouble getting my head around the proper way to do things.

I am building a sort of data-structure to support an algorithm and functionality. So suppose an outer object holds an `std::vector<Widget> vecW` and an `std::vector<Vidget> vecV`. It creates a number of objects of type `Widget`, and adds them to `vecW`. It subsequently makes a number of instances of `Vidget`, and adds them to `vecV`. (In case it matters: The memory allocated for those objects is supposed to be freed when the *outer object* is destroyed.)

Now, there is some custom logic that dictates, for each object of type `Widget` in the list, that it needs access to some of the objects of type `Vidget`. (Vice versa, if widget `w` has access to vidget `v`, then vidget `v` needs access to widget `w`.)

In C#, I would just keep a `List<vidget> ListOfVidgets` in each `Widget`, and a `List<Widget> ListOfWidgets` in each `Vidget`, and instantiate these lists based on the custom logic. Similar for Java (I believe `List<Vidget>` in C# is like `arraylist<Vidget>` in java, and a bit like `std::vector<Vidget*>`/`std::vector<Vidget>` in C++).

So I could go for `std::vector<Vidget*>` in each widget, to be instantiated based on custom logic. Is this the best approach? Or are there approaches with smart pointers (or even other approaches) that are to be preferred?

---

Edit: The lifecycle is as follows: 1) Outer object get's created and populated (with widgets/vidgets). 2) Custom logic determines the relations. 3) The data structure is used. (So no changes to relations and/or added/removed widgets during use.) 4) (only) when the outer object is destroyed, then memory needs to be freed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189292/discussion-on-question-by-willem-how-to-implement-this-data-structure-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd do.

```
class Widget {
  ...
    void AddVidget(Vidget* vidget);
  private:
    std::vector<Vidget*> vigets_;
};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vidget>> vidgets;
// Since widgets will have references to vidgets, safet
// to instantiate after vidgets (so widgets is cleaned up
// first).
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>> widgets;
...
widgets[i].add_vidget(vidjets[j].get());
```

This gives you pointer stability.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that there's no way to sanely handle the case where an inner object tries to access another inner object after the outer object has allowed it to be destroyed. But this is probably the simplest approach that works.

Comment: my comment was I don't think this reflects the OP. However, rereading it, I do not think you are correctly handling unique_ptr. There's really no way to correctly handle unique_ptr AND have additional copies of the pointer elsewhere.

Comment: So I like this, and seem to understand. It is close to the ideas in other algorithms. But everybody on the internet (and in books) tells me to stay away from "raw" pointers. So does this not apply here then?

Comment: @willem There is a lot of bad/conflicting advice out there. I strongly recommend reading through these guidelines published by Stroustrup & Sutter https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md Raw pointers are fine as long as they are non-owning.

Comment: @willlem Gaik is exactly right. Basically by accepting a raw pointer, it implies in the API to the caller that the Caller must make sure the lifetime of the pointer is longer than the lifetime of the widget. This can be subtle (I just fixed one thing, for example!) but isn't typically *too* error prone. shared_ptr is often just as error prone (with cyclic shared dependencies creating immortal objects) and shared_ptr is slow, so I tend to say "only use shared pointer if you really need to".

Comment: So after reading the recommended works, and watching Herb Sutter talk on resources, I have the feeling I "get it"now. My original question was ambiguous, because it didn't specify the lifecycle precisely. With the edit I made, this answer is still correct, but essentially so is @Galik (because the lifecycle guarantees that there are no reallocations within the outer vectors). Both answers are useful.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with using `std::vector` is that the addresses of the contained objects is subject to change when the vector changes - especially while you are filling it up.

Given your lifetime characteristics, your objects are going to be fully created **before** any relationships are built and not changed until **after** processing is over. This means you don't have a problem using pointers for the relationships.

In which case I would likely do something like this:

```
class Widget
{
public:

private:
    std::vector<class Vidget*> ListOfVidgets;
};

class Vidget
{
public:

private:    
    std::vector<class Widget*> ListOfWidgets;
};

class OuterObject
{
public:

private:
    std::vector<Widget> vecW;
    std::vector<Vidget> vecV;
};
```

That should be very efficient as the ownership semantics well established. The outer vectors own everything and the inner object vectors simply contain non-owning relationship pointers.

Comment: In general, is "non-owning relationship pointers" a good use of raw pointers?

Comment: @willem Yes it is. It is basically what raw pointers are good for in modern C++ code. All owned objects should be in a container or managed by a smart pointer. The only thing to be wary of is objects moving when you store them in a vector. In your setup that's not an issue. But if it is you can move to a `std::list` instead of a `std::vector` for the outer lists of objects.

Comment: Ok that clarifies a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would first look for a way to redesign so that this requirement goes away. It isn't usually necessary for objects to find other objects through objects above them this way. Sometimes you can arrange to pass the objects information each time they execute through their owners.

But assuming you can't change the design, you don't want to use either pointers or references. You don't want to use them because vectors can move their objects around in memory, invalidating both pointers and references. Also, ordinary pointers make ownership unclear.

Instead, use a vector of `std::shared_ptr`s to objects. Create the objects with `std::make_shared` if possible. This will manage the object's lifetime to persist until it's remove from the vector.

For one object that needs to access another, you have two choices. Use another `std::shared_ptr` to the same object if you might want to extend the lifetime of the object that's referred to until the object holding a reference to it is destroyed.

Use `std::weak_ptr` if you don't want to extend the lifetime of the object -- just remember that a weak pointer can become stale if the target's lifetime ends. You either need to ensure this never happens or check the weak pointer every time you access it. It's probably best to always check it anyway just to sanely handle error conditions.

In order of my personal preference, you could:

1. Rearchitect so that there is no need to store these references. For example, the outer object could own the relationships and pass references to the inner objects every time it invoked them. There may even be better options. The outer object can provide an API that inner objects can use and the inner objects can keep a reference to the outer object.
2. Use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. This is clean, easy to understand, and can cleanly catch any errors. It has some overhead, but only on the setup and teardown which shouldn't matter if these objects are long-lived.
3. Use a custom smart pointer. The inner objects can be given a custom smart pointer by the outer object that provides the inner objects an easy way to access the objects they need.
4. Use `unique_ptr` and vectors of raw pointers.

Answer (score -2):

Don't mess with pointers.  That is the old C style way of thinking.

If you're going to work with objects in C++, then make your lists/vectors/maps of `Widget` and `Vidget` and let the STL container own the object in question.  Then you never have to worry about dereferencing bad pointers, etc.

As for your next requirement, that `Widgets` need access to `Vidgets` and vice versa, you'll need to implement that logic in a mapping.  I think in terms of databases, so I'd have a table that maps W-to-V and V-to-W, with methods that would return **references** to the necessary objects.  When it comes to C++, I'd probably implement that using std::map with some sort of ID (artificial if need be) to the widget or vidget.

Comment: references have a few advantages, but they can still be invalidated

Comment: I think smart pointers are the solution here actually. And you can't store references, because the objects will move (inside vector at relocation, or when the vector gets passed around).

Comment: The problem is you can't just let the containers manage lifetime because the division of ownership is not well established in this case. This is an algorithm being ported from languages where those concerns do not exist, where shared ownership is the norm.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I believe that the outer container is the owner of all the objects. They remain alive until it gets destroyed.

Comment: @Galik I agree that's how it should work, but in the original code (as far as I understand it) there is no central owning container. Looks to me like `Widget`s and `Vidget`s each store references to each other. Though I may have misunderstood the question. And having written this, it also looks like circular ownership may be problematic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux He mentions an outer object that owns vectors to all the lower-level objects that have to reference each other.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux; yes, there is an outer object, that owns all. It should perhaps have played a more prominent role in the question; I wasn't sure it was important